# Weird rectangle (NSBannerView) in left top of NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview

I'm working on an macOS app and I'm experiencing a weird issue. In the left top corner of my NSTableView (above the header), a grey rectangle is shown:

[image]

(I've added an NSBox behind the NSTableView to make it more clear in the screenshot)

With the Debug View Hierarchy, I've seen it's an NSBannerView which is added to the Scroll View wrapping the Table View.

My UI is built with Interface Builder (a storyboard). I've checked and unchecked lots of checkboxes in the Interface Builder but can't find what it is. Google and Stack Overflow also don't give any clues. Googling for "NSBannerView" even only yields some macOS header files.

How to get rid of the rectangle?

**Environment details**

- macOS Mojave 10.14 Beta (18A365a)
- Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSTableRowView` and overwrite `layout`, where you hide the view

```
- (void)layout {

    [super layout];

    for (NSView * v in self.subviews) {
        if ([v.className isEqual:@"NSBannerView"]) {
            v.hidden = YES;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That sounds rather hacky to me. I ran my app on another Mac with High Sierra and didn’t see the rectangle there. It may be a macOS Mojave issue...

Comment: Yes, of course its a Mojave issue... in Mojave the OS inserts a NSBannerView to table rows.... thus this is only Mojave related... PS: the code provided is back compatible as it doesnt hurt 10.13 or earlier... i applied it to the release of my macOS app to combat this exact issue

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any idea what the purpose of the NSBannerView is?

Comment: some graphics change i guess

Comment: Is there a better way to simply opt-out of having a NSVisualEffectView / NSBannerView inserted into the view-hierarchy? This looks like a bad solution.

Comment: didn't found one and that's a perfectly fine solution, without breaking anything or referencing private API

Answer (score 0):

Making this hiding thing into `didAddSubview` might be a better solution like the example below. Because `layout` is called each time you select the row.

```
override func didAddSubview(_ subview: NSView) {
    super.didAddSubview(subview)

    if subview.className == "NSBannerView" {
        subview.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use currently use this to correct a ugly looking `NSBannerView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
    if rowView.isGroupRowStyle {
        for view in rowView.subviews {
            if let effect = view.subviews.first as? NSVisualEffectView {
                effect.material = .contentBackground // Or something else, the default material for group headers is .headerView
            }
        }
    }
}
```