# NSOutlineView adding NSBannerView to grouped rows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

New in macOS Mojave, there's a `NSBannerView` (`NSVisualEffectView`) that gets inserted behind the actual cell view in each row marked as a Grouped Row. This is adding an unnecessary visual effect-view that ruins the already styled row for our purpose. How can I stop this new behavior? There's nothing in the docs to highlight the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems the only way around this is to subclass the `NSTableRowView` and override `layout` to explicitly mark the subview as hidden. Ugly, but works. the other non-solution is to unmark these rows as `grouped`, but then they no longer float, which isn't what I'm after. Here's the solution I follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202620/3900270